# i want to select the current element when i used sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

// i want when you dragged the element in the new postion 
// the selected option is changed according to the new postion
// check the item before and the item after dragging
// the item that you daragged take the right selected option 
    
        
                    
                        1
                        2
                        3
                    
         
        
                    
                        12
                        3
                    
         
        
                    
                        1
                        2
                        3

when i used this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#contain").sortable({
          stop: function(event, ui){
               // i want to take the value of the current
              currItem=$(this).find('option:selected').text();
              alert(currentItem); // this display all item and i want the current element only 


          }
      });
```

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question includes code snippets (which you have), a description of the exact problem you have (which you don't have), what's supposed to happen (which you kind of did but not in an easy-to-comprehend maner), proper English (which you sort of have), and a specific question about the problem you have (which you don't). The last point important. You may want to rephrase your post as a question, not as a command (or you put off many potential answerers).

Comment: ok iwant to use sortable ui to order the items  i mean when i dragged the item the selected item changed of the new postion :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current item being dragged use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contain").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
         // i want to take the value of the current
        var currItem = ui.item;
        alert(currentItem); // this display all item and i want the current element only 
    }
});
```